# What is the latest or last time to pray fajr?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

Asalam aleikum

I want to asking you guys what is a last time to pray fajr some people tell me before 12 pm
it's right please confirm me

Jazakallah

Comment: Fajr time is from dawn to before sunrise.

Answer (score 1):

No it's never ever right to offer your fajr prayer after dawn
Even there's a Hadith which says that your namaz is qaza or unofferable after there are no stars left on the sky and the first sun ray has reached the earth!
So try to offer your prayers immediately after Azan because holy prophet said the best deed a Muslim can do is to offer prayer at it's right time